# A server error has occurred on text search in admin console

Tags: google-app-engine, search

When I go to the "Text Search" page of the App Engine Admin Console.  I can see my three indexes.  If I click one of these I can see various entries but any attempt to query (even a one-word query of letters only) results in a page containing:

"Server Error"

"A server error has occurred."

"Return To Applications Screen"

This happens consistently and prevents us from performing certain admin and debugging tasks so any help would be really swell.

Comment: This is a serious impediment to our administration of our search data.  Surely someone has some ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Me too facing this issue any solution?

Comment: I've heard nothing so far.

Comment: If you found any solution let me know